# How do I create an object that returns different values in different scalar contexts?

Tags: perl, scalar

I want to return a different value in string context and numeric context like [`$!`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24%21) does.  I know I can find out whether I am in list or scalar context with wantarray, but is there any way in pure Perl to determine which scalar context I am in?  I assume there is an answer in XS as well and I am willing to take that answer if there is no way do it in pure Perl.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check out the `Scalar::Util` module, specifically the `dualvar()` function:

```
use Scalar::Util qw(dualvar);

my $scalar = dualvar 10, "Hello";
my $twelve = $scalar + 2;          # $twelve = 12
my $greeting = $scalar . " world"; # $greeting = "Hello world"
```

`Scalar::Util` is part of the core distribution, and should be avaliable anywhere you have Perl.

Comment: Thanks, that does exactly what I need.  I really need to go through the Core again.  There are too many good things I have forgotten/never knew.

Answer (score 3):

While I can propose cases when this would be useful (maybe Roman Numerals), you would be better off creating an object with an integer and a string attribute.  Use the appropriate attribute in the appropriate context.

This gives you the added flexibility of being able to overload operations with 'use overload'.  In a Roman Numerals example, dualvar will work until you want to add 2 roman numerals together.